# Angular-xeditable can not access form by name from controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, x-editable

I am trying to build angualr x-editable forms within an ng-repeat but when I attempt to access the form via $scope in the controller I am getting an error.

```
<div ng-repeat="course in box.value track by $index">
   <form editable-form name="{{box.key}}{{$index}}">
      .....
      <button 
         type="button"
         class="btn btn-primary"
         ng-click="formAction(box.key, $index, 'show')">Edit
      </button>
   </form>
</div>
```

In JavaScript I have the the following but this causes an error when executed.

```
$scope.formAction = function (key, index, action) {
    var formName = key + index;
    if (action === 'show') {
         //console.log(formName) shows correct form name yet
        //Error!! TypeError: Cannot read property '$show' of undefined
        $scope[formName].$show();
    }
};
```

The x-editable manual says says form name="{{box.key}}{{$index}}" should create a property on the $scope but when I console.log($scope) I cant find the property

Answer (score 6):

Actually x-editable adds the form to the scope, but not to the same scope where `formAction` is. ng-repeat creates a scope for every item it renders, which are the children of the original scope, you'll find the forms on those scopes.

A solution is to pass the child scope to formAction, 'this' below:

```
<button 
     type="button"
     class="btn btn-primary"
     ng-click="formAction(box.key, $index, 'show', this)">Edit
</button>
```

Then call `$show()` on the form found on the child scope:

```
$scope.formAction = function (key, index, action, childScope) {
    var formName = key + index;
    if (action === 'show') {
        childScope[formName].$show();
    }
};
```